# how to save zsh history after iterm2 restart

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I'm using **iterm2** with **zsh** and **oh my zsh**.

When I quit iterm2 and re-open it, my history is gone. I'd like for it to persist. On my old machine, this worked by default, but since it doesn't on my new machine, I'm having to learn a little more about shells than I used to need to know.

Potentially relevant: my .zsh_history file requires sudo in order to open. Also, I don't share history across tabs, the way I know many people with iterm/zsh/ohmyzsh seem to complain about.

Comment: If you can only open your `.zsh_history` with sudo, it is a clear indicator, that your user account is not the owner of the file. You can check the permissions with `stat .zsh_history`. Ensure that "Uid" and "Gid" match up with the output of `id`. Change ownership with `chown UID:GID .zsh_history`. I would guess that happened when migrating the file from your old machine, you may want to ensure, that other files in your home directory are not affected similarly.

Comment: This should be an answer ^^